# Same print statement provides different output for sorting algorithm (Insertion Sort)

Tags: python, list, sorting, output

I have coded up the algorithm for insertion sort and have ensured that it works; however, depending on how I print the sorted list, the output is different. For example,

```
x = some_unsorted_list
x = insertionSort(x)
print(x)
```

will print the sorted list just fine. On the other hand,

```
x = some_unsorted_list
insertionSort(x)
print(x)
```

will print some partially sorted-unsorted list. Here is my code for selection sort:

```
def insertionSort(L):
    endList = len(L) - 1 

    for i in range(1,endList+1,1): 
        insertVal = L[i]  
        j = i - 1 

        while j >= 0 and L[j] > insertVal:
            L[j+1] = L[j]    
            j -= 1          
        L[j+1] = insertVal  
    #print(L)
    return L
```

Note that the print statement commented out always provides the sorted list, which is causing my confusion.

**Edit (Important information I left out):** Here's how I'm calling the insertion sort. Let v1, v2, and v3 be unsorted lists.

```
for i in [v1,v2,v3]:
    x = list(i)
    insertionSort(x)
    print(x)
```

And recall, this is where errors arise. However the following code **does not** produce errors:

```
print(insertionSort(v1))
print(insertionSort(v2))
print(insertionSort(v3))
```

Comment: Python is a somewhat unusual language in that values are *bound* to variables, rather than values being *assigned* to variables (copied in and out, as it were). Whatever the issue here is, it's likely in the caller, rather than in the sorting function. Providing a [mcve] would help others help you.

Comment: Perhaps I'm performing your test differently, but I always get both lists sorted with my attempts.  Perhaps as torek suggested it would help if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also in my different attempts, the [id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of x and L are always the same and never change.  So, this would be consistent with x always being sorted in my attempts.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a variable to a function, a new copy is made. So, when you are passing `x` to your function, a new variable `L` will be made which will have the same value as `x`.

Now, we have 2 different variables named `x` and `L`.

In your function, you are making changes to `L` and outside the function, you are printing `x`. Therefore, you are getting wrong results. Because `L` was sorted **NOT** `x`.

#### The difference among codes

In your first code snippet `x = insertionSort(x)`, overrides the value of `x` with the value returned by function (which will be a sorted list always). So, it prints the right result.
In your second code snippet, you are **NOT** overriding the value of `x`. Therefore, you are getting wrong results.

Comment: The function does modify the list object in place, assuming it receives an actual list object. If the caller's `x` is bound to the same list as the callee's `L`, printing `x` in the caller will print the sorted list. If the function receives some other object, though, things may get trickier.

Comment: Thank you your answer certainly helps clarify some things! I updated the question to further clarify how I'm really calling insertion sort -- maybe this alters answers.

Comment: @PM25 the answer remains the same. You have to assign the result of `insertionSort(x)` to `x` like this: `x = insertionSort(x)`. Keep in mind, that this value will be overwritten again and again. So, results for `v1`, `v2` will be lost. A better approach is to create an array `results = []` outside the loop and append sorted lists in it: `results.append(x)` inside the loop after  `x = insertionSort(x)`